# Cron job not executing on Amazon server

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, cron

My website is hosted on Amazon server, I have a PHP that sends emails to the user, What I did is setup a cron job

```
3 * * * * php LINK to Abc.php
```

SO that it would run after 3 minutes. BUt I am not receving any mail that shows the script is not running.

- I checked the logs that showed /var/syslog

> CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] &&
>   find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin
>   +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)

Over my head.
Then I tried this command to check the cron job `crontab-l` still nothing happend.
anyone who can help me in debugging

**EDIT1**
It says in log files now..

```
CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

If I do PHP Path to file from terminal.. it runs fine and I receive an email as well...
Please help in this regard

Comment: cron job or email problem?

Comment: @Dagon it is cron job,, because if I run the script in browser it works fine

Comment: have you set the `MAILTO=` in the crontab file?

Comment: @Dagon all the script is present in the php file..why MAILTO in crontab file? :)

Comment: you will get any errors then

Comment: if you add the MAILTO Variable then any error will be emailed to you, otherwise you are not going to see it

Comment: @Dagon I cannot run the job in crontab.. it is running fine with php command at terminal

Answer (score 1):

Try `3 * * * * /var/lib/php5 /path/to/Abc.php`

Comment: Whoops, it's actually probably /usr/bin/php5. You can run "which php5" to see where it's installed on your computer, but I believe that is the default.

Comment: its a rare system where the php path is required, only seen it when you are running multiple versions

Comment: @amandagreenlee  I cannot run the job in crontab.. it is running fine with php command at terminal

Answer (score 0):

Check that the link you are passing to PHP is not a web link which means it doesn't start with HTTP, rather it should be path to the PHP file.